# Curly Brace Initialisation with std::string

Tags: c++, stdstring, curly-braces

I have been using curly brace initialisation more and more recently. Although I found a difference to round bracket initialisation in this case and I was wondering why.

If I do:

```cpp
const std::string s(5, '=');
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

I get:

```
=====
```

This is what I expect. But if I do:

```cpp
const std::string s{5, '='};
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

I get:

```
=
```

Why is this?

Edit: For the benefit for anyone that sees this. There is an unprintable character before the `=` in the second output. It just doesn't show on stackoverflow. Looks like:

[image]

Comment: `{}` should be used when constructing from a list of any sort (including empty, or one item). `()` should be used for all of the "other" constructors.

Comment: Is that a string of two characters?  One that is the unprintable character 0x05 (ASCII ENQ) and the second that is the character `=`?  In other words when you say "I get `=`" you are only showing the `=` and the 0x05 char before it is unprintable, do I understand correctly?

Comment: @Wyck Sorry yes there is an unprintable character before the `=` and it shows as a box

Comment: Perfect.  I want to give Kudos and upvoting for pasting the actual characters into the question.  They just don't pass through the Stack Overflow software.  Those that have the ability to do so can edit the question and see the original text with the 5 character are indeed intact.

Comment: Maybe a screenshot is acceptable in this case to demonstrate what it actually looks like.

Comment: So much for "uniform" initialization syntax. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```cpp
const std::string s(5, '=');
```

uses the constructor taking a *count* and the character, *ch* (as well as an allocator):

```cpp
constexpr basic_string( size_type count, CharT ch,
                        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

But

```cpp
const std::string s{5, '='};
```

uses

```cpp
constexpr basic_string( std::initializer_list<CharT> ilist,
                        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

which means that `5` will be converted to a `char` and your string will therefore have the size `2`. The first character will have the value `5` and the other will be `=`.